# Exporting datagridview to excel conflict with excel iterop

Tags: c#, namespaces

I have a listbox which passes by drag and drop to a datagridview, when added the excel interop to the namespace keyword point in drag and drop event is conflicting with the same keyword in excel interop.
May be stupid question but can anyone help 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I removed using System. Drawing from namespace and called point with its fully qualified name Sysytem.Drawing.Point and there is no more conflict with using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel in using point and runs smoothly with using drag and drop.
Thanks for anyone tried to help in this simple problem.